# Django Rest Framework and field-level permissions

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I want to build an API with field-level permissions. I get these permissions from a database table, but where in the REST framework is the place to check if a user can perform CRUD operations on the field of an object?

```
database --- model ---- ModelSerializer ---- ModelViewSet --- browser
```

In the ModelSerializer?  Here i can drop fields before they get to the viewset but i don't have access to the request.user by default, so i have to implement that, which can be done but doesn't work well with other 3th party libraries i have (django-rest-swagger)

or in the ModelViewset? Where i can override the list, create, update and destroy methods to drop fields where the user doesn't have access to. But this doesn't work well with my Metadata implementation because that gets the metadata directly from the serializer.

Or maybe both? Eg: drop not-allowed reads *in* the serializer when the model is fetched *by* the serializer, and drop not-allowed-writes in the viewset *before* they get passed back *to* the serializer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good section in the DRF docs on permissions [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/). A good place for handling (and checking them) is in the viewset. To copy an example from the docs:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class ExampleView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        content = {
            'status': 'request was permitted'
        }
        return Response(content)
```

If you want to have a custom permission checker you can define your own, and specify replace `IsAuthenticated` with your own class

Answer (score 8):

You can create different serializers depending on the fields you want for a particular request. Then you need to override the `get_serializer_class()` function in your view and decide the serializer according to your logic.

As per the DRF docs on [`get_serializer_class()`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#genericapiview)

> May be overridden to provide dynamic behavior, such as using different
>   serializers for read and write operations, or providing different
>   serializers to different types of users.

For example:

```
class MyView(..):

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.user.is_staff: # check if staff user
            return FullAccountSerializer 
        return BasicAccountSerializer
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement the custom permission good to use modelviewset in DRF.

```
from rest_framework import status, viewsets

class MyModelViewsets(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = # queryset
    serializer_class = # serializer class
    permission_classes = (# custom permission class her)
```

If you want all apply the custom permission to all endpoints the specify it in the settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {

    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
        # add custom permission here
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GenericView, by default DRF put the request object into the context of the serializer object. You can access the user info by

`self.context['request'].user`

Answer (score 0):

```
from utils.mixins import MultiSerializerViewSetMixin


class UserViewSet(MultiSerializerViewSetMixin, ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    serializer_action_classes = {
        'update': UserDetailSerializer,
    }
    permission_classes = (UserPermission,)
    queryset = User.objects.all()
```

source code for the MultiSerializerViewSetMixin:
https://gist.github.com/gonz/10044002

i managed my problem with two seriazliers:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import serializers


class UserSerializerMixin(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    is_superuser = serializers.BooleanField(read_only=True)
    first_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, allow_blank=True)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, allow_blank=True)
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=False, allow_blank=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.first_name = validated_data.get('first_name', instance.first_name)
        instance.last_name = validated_data.get('last_name', instance.last_name)
        instance.email = validated_data.get('email', instance.email)
        password = validated_data.get('password', '')
        if password:
            instance.set_password(password)
            instance.save()
        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = User


class UserSerializer(UserSerializerMixin):
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=30)
    password = serializers.CharField(
        max_length=128, write_only=True,
        style={'input_type': 'password'})


class UserDetailSerializer(UserSerializerMixin):
    username = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(
        max_length=128, write_only=True,
        style={'input_type': 'password'},
        required=False, allow_blank=True
    )
```

it is possible you could make use of the MultiSerializerViewSetMixin, i found it at work back last year and use mixins to create two different yet similar serializers.